# It seems that I found a simple bug for Springframework v4.2.0?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I try to use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse` in my project's unit-test, offered by `spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar`.
When I trigger its method of `setContentType()`, the whole thread progress goes dead/hung! until my `@Test(timeout=5000)` annotation breaks the test-case hunging!
I then try to replace the spring-mock package by a previous relase of `spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar`.
Guess what?! Everything goes fine!

Is it a silly bug of the mock-package of Springframework 4.2.0?

If it is, where should report it? since I can NOT find a bugzilla for Springframework on web?

Comment: Spring uses [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/spr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) as their bug tracker.

Comment: You might want to debug your test to see what's actually happening, before you report it as a bug.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

OK friends, thanks for all of your quick response really!
I found the reason why:
spring-mock/test-package (spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar) may never works lonely! MockHttpServletResponse.setContentType() of v4.2.0 innerly uses org.springframework.http.MediaType, which locates inside spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar! (Which is missing)
But in v4.1.7, MockHttpServletResponse.setContentType() calls nothing outside the spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar.
Thus why spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar goes dead/hung, and spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar works fine!
It's surely NOT a bug!
However, I still can NOT understand why it goes dead/hung, instead of throws ClassNotFoundException in my TestCase?!
Thus, I raise another question: [TestCase make up by JUnit + Spring-Mock package runs into a dead-hung, when other spring-jar files are missing! (Never a ClassNotFound exception!?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047451/testcase-make-up-by-junit-spring-mock-package-runs-into-a-dead-hung-when-othe)
Hope any of you may give me the correct answer!
Many thanks again!