# TestCase make up by JUnit + Spring-Mock package runs into a dead-hung, when other spring-jar files are missing! (Never a ClassNotFound exception!?)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I'm building up a TestCase by Junit4 + Springframework4's Mock-Package.

When I call `MockHttpServletResponse.setContentType()` or `MockAsyncContext.complete()`, the whole task-thread goes dead-hung (never returns from upper calling methods!)

Since it's an asynchronous testcase, the other part of the main caller of the test-case is still running: Waiting for the dead/hung async-thread to complete its job! And never returns back to finish the testcase, even I bind `@Test(timeout)` annotation!

I later study the .java source file, which find out that `MockHttpServletResponse.setContentType()` internally uses `MetaType.class` and `MockAsyncContext.complete()` internally uses `WebUtils.class`, both does not belong to Springframework4's Mock/Test-Package (spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar)!

After a further study of the head-import for `MockHttpServletResponse.java` and `MockAsyncContext.java` files, I known in order to make all mock-obj working fine, I need to bind 3-more .jar files: spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar + spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar + spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Now Junit3/4 + JunitPref1.9 + spring4-mock works OK now!

However, I still want to known: Even I add `throws Throwable` to all my `testXxx()` method and `throws Exception` to all my `setUp()`/`tearDown()` in TestCase, why it never report `ClassNotFoundException`?! but just goes to dead/hung instead?!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the reason why NO Exception/Error can be seen from the console where my TestCase main calling runs!
That is the target-tested task is based on Servlet3 async-request + JDK5 thread-pool! It is running inside a (or many) complete different thread(s), other than the main TestCase caller!
And the ant-console only shows the TestCase's thread running information!
I do used to run JConsole + JVisualVM to find the failure thread of those Servlet3 async-request tasks, but can NOT get their thread-id or stack-trace info!
I believe it is because that since some spring-jar file is missing, it is actually NOT ClassNotFoundException but NoClassDefFoundError that throws! which will terminate the whole thread!
That's why JConsole + JVisualVM tools find nothing at all!
Is there any toolkit any of you suggest, can view the history of terminated thread-stack-trace?!
Thanks again to all of you!